# Collections Mapping vs Association mapping

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am very newbie to hibernate. I am learning about Mappings in hibernate in which case i have to go for Collection Mapping and Association Mapping. My confusion is "`If an entity or class has collection of values for a particular variable, then we can map those values using any one of the collection interfaces available in java`"

in that case why we go  for collection instead of onetomany. Please provide a simple real time example for when we use collection and association mapping

Comment: I'm not a Hibernate specialist and I usually to try to use JPA annotations only. I think in JPA it's often easier to go for a `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToOne` relationship. Also I'm not sure to understand your question. Are you wondering whether you need to use Map or Collections in your underlying java model?

Comment: @phoenix7360 please refer this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_or_mappings.htm

Comment: OK so my understanding is that it's really down to your data model and the types of relationships it contains. I would say that if you business requirement doesn't force you to have Collection mapping stick with association mappings because it's easier and works well enough. I'm sure there might be some special cases in which you have to use mapping but that really depends on the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused in Collection and Association.

It is not necessary that every association must be a single Object, it can be collection of Objects.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock")
public Set<StockDailyRecord> getStockDailyRecords() {
    return this.stockDailyRecords;
}
```

See : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: why this answer was marked as correct ? I dont understand you answer at all. The question is about when to use Collection mapping and when to use association mapping. The thing is about Value objects and Entity objects. If you map from entity to value object - use collection mapping, if you make association between two entities - use associations.

Answer (score 0):

Collections Mapping and  Association mapping   are not comparable, I mean these reside on different layer of abstraction and Association mapping  use Collections Mapping if required.